# Create a LiveCD Distrobution .iso From Scratch

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso, live-cd, live-environment

**What have I done:**

1. Started with the Ubuntu Mini.iso 20.04 I have basically created a custom build in a VM environment
2. I have installed xfce4 as the the Desktop engine.
3. I have installed Nemo and set it as the Preferred FileManager.
4. I have customized the theming and xfce panel layout.

**What I want to do:**
I want to create a  LIVECD .iso so I can give it to others to install in our environment. Just like you would if you download Ubuntu 20.04, basically I want to create my own customized distribution.

**What have I read and tried:**
I went through this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch
It did work and I got a bootable .iso

**What is the problem:**
I don't understand why all my changes I made to the host machine are not in the Live environment or install.

I made the above changes .... but when I went through the tutorial and created the .iso I booted it up and its just the default XFCE desktop.

So, I went further and ran through the installation of the newly created .iso, and none of my changes of the host are there.

I am not really sure what I am missing.

My question is.....is that the correct set of procedures to follow? or is there another tutorial I should be reading.

**Please I do not want to use**, cubic, pinguyos builder, clonezilla or an thing like that, my goal is to build and understand this process myself, but It is very hard to find clear documentation on what to do.

Comment: I think the tutorial is a bit misleading in that regard. Changes you made to the "host" system will not be incorporated in the ISO. The `debootstrap` command installs whatever release you tell it to into the chroot environment. All changes you want to incorporate in the ISO have to be done in the chroot environment.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so you are saying the configs and other modifications made need to put the chroot environment. That makes sense...I was thinking the host an chroot  were one in the same but they are not right?